# substring() with () in the vector

Tags: r, substring

I'd like to break this column into 2, using the first bracket as the separater. I used word(x,2, sep = "(") but I got an error. I understand that R doesn't like brackets as `sep`. I want to use `"("` as a `sep` because the data is not consistently recorded, on some rows, we have a space between the country and the state, on some other rows we don't.

How do I get around this? Thank you.

```
x <- c("United States (Alabama) ", "United States (California) ", 
"United States (California) ", "United States (California) ", 
"United States (California) ", "United States (Colorado) ", 
"United States (Colorado) ", "United States (Colorado) ", 
"United States(Connecticut) ", "United States(Connecticut) "
)
word(x,2,sep = "(").
```

> Error in stri_locate_all_regex(string, pattern, omit_no_match = TRUE,  :
> Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN, context=`(`)

Comment: please include the entire dataframe

Comment: `read.table(text = gsub('\\)', '', x), sep = '(', strip.white = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `sub/scan` approach.

```
matrix(trimws(scan(what = character(), text = sub("\\)", "", x), sep = "(")), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#Read 20 items
#      [,1]            [,2]         
# [1,] "United States" "Alabama"    
# [2,] "United States" "California" 
# [3,] "United States" "California" 
# [4,] "United States" "California" 
# [5,] "United States" "California" 
# [6,] "United States" "Colorado"   
# [7,] "United States" "Colorado"   
# [8,] "United States" "Colorado"   
# [9,] "United States" "Connecticut"
#[10,] "United States" "Connecticut"
```

**Explanation**

The code above uses `scan` to break each string in two by a `sep` character. Since the `sep` must have length 1, choose one of `"("` or `")"`. I have chosen `"("`, so before, remove the other one, `")"`, with `sub`. The rest is straightforward.

The instructions sequence is:

```
tmp <- sub("\\)", "", x)
tmp <- scan(what = character(), text = tmp, sep = "(")
tmp <- trimws(tmp)
matrix(tmp, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can try `strsplit` + `gsub` like below

```
trimws(
  gsub(
    "\\(|\\)",
    "",
    do.call(
      rbind,
      strsplit(x,
        "((?<=\\s)\\()|(?=)\\(",
        perl = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
      [,1]            [,2]
 [1,] "United States" "Alabama"
 [2,] "United States" "California"
 [3,] "United States" "California"
 [4,] "United States" "California" 
 [5,] "United States" "California"
 [6,] "United States" "Colorado"
 [7,] "United States" "Colorado"
 [8,] "United States" "Colorado"
 [9,] "United States" "Connecticut"
[10,] "United States" "Connecticut"
```

Comment: Why are the last two US singular?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for correcting me. You are right. I had a typo for the pattern in `strsplit`. Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `stringr::word`? If so, the `sep` argument is interpreted as a regular expression. You could either escape the '(' like this:

```
word(x, 2, sep = "\\(")
```

or you can use the `fixed` function:

```
word(x, 2, sep = fixed("("))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use this regex `\(([^\)]+)\)`, which will capture the state (assuming that is what you are after).

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x = df, pattern = "\(([^\)]+)\)")
```

Which yields the list

```
[1] "Alabama"

[[2]]
[1] "California"

[[3]]
[1] "California"

[[4]]
[1] "California"

[[5]]
[1] "California"

[[6]]
[1] "Colorado"

[[7]]
[1] "Colorado"

[[8]]
[1] "Colorado"

[[9]]
[1] "Connecticut"

[[10]]
[1] "Connecticut"
```